# Trying to get same result by xpath and css element

Tags: php, web-crawler, goutte

Im trying to get the same result from a site by using dom elements and xpath. So i can make this crawler dynamic for more sites, so that i only have to fill in url and what type(xpath, domelement).

```
 $url = 'https://#/';
        $xpath = "/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/span[1]";        
        $client = new Client();
        $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
            'timeout' => 60,
        ));
        $client->setClient($guzzleClient);
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
        $crawler->filter('.rate')->filter('.gold')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->text()."\n";
        });

        $result = $crawler->filterXPath($xpath);
        var_dump($result);
```

result should be, gold price like this code piece outputs: $crawler->filter('.rate')->filter('.gold')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->text()."\n";
        });

If anything is unclear please let me know!

Comment: What's the problem with the given code?

Comment: @NicoHaase the problem is that the filterXpath outputs the whole site and not just the gold price like the $node does.

Comment: And what keeps you from adjusting the XPath selector? Why don't you use more specific parts there, like classes or IDs - or just ask the provider of that data for an API? You should have their contact already, as scraping that data should not be done without explicit consent....

Comment: Thanks for the answer! well if I adjust the XPath selector to much wont it be hard to make it dynamic for other sites? Unfortunately they have no api. And yes we do have the consent

Comment: Any XPath selector is fragile, and yes, making it dynamic for multiple pages is difficult

Comment: Ah ok thanks didnt know that, any tips for making it more dynamic like using DOMElements?

Comment: Well, don't use XPath. Use proper APIs that are decoupled from the markup structure

Comment: Thank you for the information! I will try to get APIs for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

If you want to fetch the gold rate then you can use the below selectors.

**xpath**

```
//ul[@class='rates-widget list-inline']//span[@class='rate gold']
```

**CSS**

```
ul.rates-widget.list-inline span.rate.gold
```